# Appending is multiplying instead of just taking two

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that will only print a number max 2 times from a list onto a new list. But my list is rather multiplying the number of times the number is present on the list.

My code:

```
def main_function(org_list):
    counter = 0
    mod_list = []
    new_list = []

    for i in range(0,len(org_list)):
        if org_list not in mod_list:
            mod_list.append(org_list[i])
    
    for j in range(0,len(mod_list)):
        for k in range(0,len(org_list)):
            if mod_list[j] == org_list[k]:
                counter = counter+1
        if counter >= 2:
            new_list.append(mod_list[j])
            new_list.append(mod_list[j])
        elif counter == 1:
            new_list.append(mod_list[j])
        counter = 0
    return new_list

main_function([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8])
```

The output I get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

The output I need:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8]
```

Comment: ```if org_list not in mod_list:```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the expected output my guess is that, instead of this

```py
    for i in range(0,len(org_list)):
        if org_list not in mod_list:
            mod_list.append(org_list[i])
```

you meant to do this (org_list[i] instead of org_list)

```py
    for i in range(0,len(org_list)):
        if org_list[i] not in mod_list:
            mod_list.append(org_list[i])
```